# DMX Sub Query Issue

Tags: sql, ssas, dmx-ssas

I am trying to query the Mining Model I have created in SSAS. And my query is like this:

```
SELECT FLATTENED MODEL_NAME, NODE_UNIQUE_NAME, 
     [PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME], NODE_TYPE, NODE_DESCRIPTION, NODE_SUPPORT, 
     (SELECT ATTRIBUTE_VALUE, [SUPPORT] 
      FROM NODE_DISTRIBUTION 
      WHERE ATTRIBUTE_VALUE = 'True') AS ND 
FROM DecisionTreeMM.CONTENT 
WHERE NODE_DESCRIPTION <> '';
```

But it gives error as

> Error (Data mining): A Boolean expression is not allowed in the
>   context at line 2, column 65.

Comment: You cannot select multiple columns within a subquery statement like that -- what should `ND` be in this case -- what are your desired results?  Perhaps you could `join` on the `node_distribution` table to return the appropriate values?

Comment: Row in 'DecisionTreeMM.CONTENT' itself containing the 'NODE_DISTRIBUTION '. Also if I take out the 'WHERE ATTRIBUTE_VALUE = 'True'' where clause in subquery it works.